# Retrieving and setting DataTable columns widths

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Primefaces DataTable with dynamic, draggable and resizable columns. I need to store users' preference of datatable setup - which columns are displayed, their order and width.
There is no problem to retrieve displayed columns order in the backing bean, but I am struggling with widths.

```
<composite:implementation>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" update="" id="editMode" action="#{cc.attrs.bean.saveColumnsConfiguration(cc.clientId)}"/>
    <p:dataTable id="editTable" widgetVar="editTable" var="entity" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.loadEntities(0)}" 
                 rows="5" resizableColumns="true" draggableColumns="true" lazy="true" >
        <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.bean.selectedColumns}" var="col">
            <p:column width="#{col.width}">
                <f:attribute name="property" value="#{col.property}" />
            </p:column>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:dataTable>
</composite:implementation>
```

And in the backing bean:

```
public void saveColumnsConfiguration(String clientId) {
    FacesContext currentInstance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent findComponent = currentInstance.getViewRoot().findComponent(clientId+":editTable");
    DataTable table = (DataTable)findComponent;
    List<UIColumn> columns1 = table.getColumns();
    for (UIColumn c : columns1) {
        System.out.println(currentInstance.getViewRoot().findComponent(c.getClientId()).getAttributes().get("property") +" "+ c.getWidth());
    }
}
```

In the DOM inspector, `<th/>` elements have style attribute with ie. "width: 100px" set as provided by `col` variable. However, in the backing bean all columns have c.getWidth()=0. I also tried `<p:column style="width: #{col.width}px">` and retrieve it in bean by `c.getStyle()` which results in `width: 0px`.

I also tried colResize ajax event - it's giving me NumberFormatExpression on Integer.parseInt, because the event is returning decimal point numbers.

The other thing I need to do is set the column widths of datatable scaled to the user's screen. I have column sizes stored in % but need to transform these to pixel sizes according to screen width before rendering. If I set the widths in pixels, the browser scales the width properly, but on column width change by user, the columns jumps to their real pixel sizes which messes up the whole table. Any idea how to do this?